# Find the time difference in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

df1:

```
    time_1            a      b        c
0   1.675168e+09    -90.56  5.28    -6.23
1   1.675168e+09    -87.98  5.27    -5.68
2   1.675168e+09    -83.96  14.74   -9.44
3   1.675168e+09    -85.58  -5.72   -5.27
4   1.675168e+09    -95.13  -4.15   -5.46
5   1.675168e+09    -90.56  5.28    -6.23
6   1.675168e+09    -87.98  5.27    -5.68
7   1.675168e+09    -83.96  14.74   -9.44
8   1.675168e+09    -85.58  -5.72   -5.27
9   1.675168e+09    -95.13  -4.15   -5.46
```

df2:

```
     time_2              x          y         z
0   1.675168e+09        -6.64   542.397494  2.25
1   1.675168e+09        -6.64   541.233179  2.25
2   1.675169e+09        -6.63   567.644365  2.25
3   1.675169e+09        -6.63   530.368776  2.25
4   1.675170e+09        -6.63   552.896863  2.25
```

I would like to get the difference of time. ie,time_1 in the df1 minus all the time_2 values in df2.

df:

```
       time_1 - time_2              a      b     c    y
0     1.675168e+09 - 1.675168e+09
1     1.675168e+09 - 1.675168e+09
2     1.675168e+09 - 1.675169e+09
3     1.675168e+09 - 1.675169e+09
4     1.675168e+09 - 1.675170e+09
5
6
7
```

and go on

Answer (score 0):

**Update** according your comment, use `merge` with `how='cross'`:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, how='cross').assign(time=lambda x: x.pop('time_1') - x.pop('time_2'))
print(out)

# Output
        a      b     c     x           y     z    time
0  -90.56   5.28 -6.23 -6.64  542.397494  2.25     0.0
1  -90.56   5.28 -6.23 -6.64  541.233179  2.25     0.0
2  -90.56   5.28 -6.23 -6.63  567.644365  2.25 -1000.0
3  -90.56   5.28 -6.23 -6.63  530.368776  2.25 -1000.0
4  -90.56   5.28 -6.23 -6.63  552.896863  2.25 -2000.0
...
45 -95.13  -4.15 -5.46 -6.64  542.397494  2.25     0.0
46 -95.13  -4.15 -5.46 -6.64  541.233179  2.25     0.0
47 -95.13  -4.15 -5.46 -6.63  567.644365  2.25 -1000.0
48 -95.13  -4.15 -5.46 -6.63  530.368776  2.25 -1000.0
49 -95.13  -4.15 -5.46 -6.63  552.896863  2.25 -2000.0
```

---

You can join your dataframes (based on indexes):

```
out = df2.join(df1).assign(time=lambda x: x.pop('time_1') - x.pop('time_2'))
print(out)

# Output
      x           y     z      a      b     c    time
0 -6.64  542.397494  2.25 -90.56   5.28 -6.23     0.0
1 -6.64  541.233179  2.25 -87.98   5.27 -5.68     0.0
2 -6.63  567.644365  2.25 -83.96  14.74 -9.44 -1000.0
3 -6.63  530.368776  2.25 -85.58  -5.72 -5.27 -1000.0
4 -6.63  552.896863  2.25 -95.13  -4.15 -5.46 -2000.0
```

Comment: when we merge two dataframes we need 50 rows. we need to substract time_1[0] with time_2 [0], time_2 [1], time_2 [2], time_2 [3], time_2 [4]and then substract time_1[1] with time_2 [0], time_2 [1], time_2 [2], time_2 [3], time_2 [4] and so on.

Comment: @user20777609. I updated my answer according your comment. You are looking for `merge` with `how='cross'`.

Comment: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 9.28 GiB for an array with shape (8, 155650000) and data type float64. I am getting error

Comment: You have to use Dask or PySpark to accomplish this task. What do you want to do with this data?

Comment: I need to merge the dataframes and see the difference of the time. And then, i need to find the rows with time difference <= 0.01 sec

Comment: Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_1': [1, -1, 1.5]},
                 )

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'time_2': [-2.5, 1.5, 2.6]},
                  )
#combine the two dataframes into one, concat on column axis
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1],axis="columns")
#assign new column with difference between time
df2 = df2.assign(Time_diff = df2['time_1'] - df2['time_2'])
```

Comment: when we merge two dataframes we need 50 rows. we need to substract time_1[0] with time_2 [0], time_2 [1], time_2 [2], time_2 [3], time_2 [4]and then substract time_1[1] with time_2 [0], time_2 [1], time_2 [2], time_2 [3], time_2 [4] and so on.